# SQL Query not returning desired result with NOT LIKE

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running a simple query where comparing a `TEXT` column using `NOT LIKE` but the results are not coming correct. Tried a lot but no luck. Here is the query :

```
SELECT *
FROM `restaurant_session_log`
WHERE `restId` = '176'
OR branchId = '203'
OR  `multi_vendorId` LIKE '%,176%' 
OR  `multi_vendorId` LIKE '%,176,%' 
OR  `multi_vendorId` LIKE '%176,%' 
OR  `multi_vendorId` LIKE '%[176]%' 
AND (`excluded_branch_id` NOT LIKE '%,203%'  OR `excluded_branch_id` NOT LIKE '%,203,%'  OR `excluded_branch_id` NOT LIKE '%203,%'  OR `excluded_branch_id` NOT LIKE '%[203]%' )
```

And here is the result:
[image: screenshot]

Now the correct result would only include 2nd row, with `id = 27707` because I have mentioned in the query to bring result where `excluded_branch_id != %203%` but I don't understand why it's giving the row with `203` in `excluded_branch_id` column.

Please help!

Comment: Try with `not like [203]`

Comment: the main reason is restid is same for both so it is meeting the condition as restid=176 and (since inside it is OR so if any of them mets ) then it will result

Comment: What is with `[203]`? If there is a single value then you store it wrapped inside `[]`?

Comment: That's supposed to also have multiple values e.g. `[203,176,345]` ... We have wrapped in square brackets just for ease when retrieving in PHP in form of Array. I understand now its not a good practice but that's how the existing system has been running and handed over to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use REGEXP to simplify the matching. The following matches `203` if it has word boundaries on both sides of it:

```
(excluded_branch_id IS NULL OR excluded_branch_id NOT REGEXP '[[:<:]]203[[:>:]]')
```

E.g:

```
SELECT
    '203,111' REGEXP '[[:<:]]203[[:>:]]', -- 1
    '111,203' REGEXP '[[:<:]]203[[:>:]]', -- 1
    '1,203,1' REGEXP '[[:<:]]203[[:>:]]', -- 1
    '1120311' REGEXP '[[:<:]]203[[:>:]]'  -- 0
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot Salman for reminding me of `REGEXP`

Answer (score 1):

Don't store multiple values in a single string!  Don't put numeric values in a string!  This is the root cause of your problems.

Sometimes, you cannot change someone's really, really, really bad data modeling decision.  Your obvious problem is parentheses.

But, the logic would be simplified if you used `find_in_set()`.  I think you intend:

```
WHERE (`restId` = '176' OR branchId = '203' OR
       find_in_set(176, `multi_vendorId`)
      ) AND
      (find_in_set(203, `excluded_branch_id`)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! So I should go after breaking it up and normalising right? Nothing can be done using the current structure to get desired result? Anyway using a subquery or any other trick?

Comment: @hyd00 . .. I answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

$query = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE year_released NOT LIKE '200_';"

$result = db_query($query, array(':movies' => $value));